# Using Squid proxy server to redirect web request

Tags: python, redirect, proxy, squid

I am trying to set up a squid3 proxy on my laptop.  I am new to all this, I was able to configure my desktop to use the proxy just as a pass through.  The next thing I would like to do is redirect web requests.  I've added this line in my squid.conf file

```
url_rewrite_program /usr/local/bin/redirect.py
url_rewrite_children 5
```

The program I have simply returns the web address for Google, for testing purposes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    new_url = "301:http://google.com\n" 
    sys.stdout.write(new_url)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Now when I use the proxy on my desktop, all web requests are redirected to Google, but it then gets caught in an infinite redirect loop and never actually opens the page. I'm not sure what to try next.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your program would try to redirect 
`http://google.com`
to
`http://google.com` - a perfect loop.

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted, it's the explanation, the solution is pretty obvious from there, the program shouldn't redirect when the url is already google.com.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) I find this super powerful.